# Shorten an existing matrix to a specific number of columns

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have a bunch of 2xN matrices and I would like to shorten the matrices so they are all 2x3 instead. For example if I have

```
u = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
v = [[2,4,5,6,1], [8,9,0,1,2]]
```

I would like to change it so that there are only three columns for each matrix, but still two rows.
So:

```
u = [[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]
v = [[2,4,5], [8,9,0]]
```

Is there a shortcut way/specific function that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` to achieve the result.

```
u = [el[:3] for el in u]
v = [el[:3] for el in v]
print(u)
print(v)
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
[[2, 4, 5], [8, 9, 0]]
```